# How to make the error was seen regardless of their location in the block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

**1) everything works, the console output warning :**

```
def read_from_file
    begin
      10/0 
      File.readlines("#{@owner}_cart.txt").each { |i| @items << i.to_real_item }
      @items.uniq!
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      File.open("#{@owner}_cart.txt", 'w'){}
      puts "file #{@owner}_cart.txt"
    end
  end
```

**console :**

```
E:/work/storeapp3/app/storeapp/shop/cart.rb:20:in `/': divided by 0 (ZeroDivisionError)
        from E:/work/storeapp3/app/storeapp/shop/cart.rb:20:in `read_from_file'
        from add_to_cart.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

**2) Here mistake of "10/0" is not shown:**

```
def read_from_file
    begin
      File.readlines("#{@owner}_cart.txt").each { |i| @items << i.to_real_item }
      @items.uniq!
      10/0 
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      File.open("#{@owner}_cart.txt", 'w'){}
      puts "file #{@owner}_cart.txt"
    end
  end
```

**console :**

```
E:\work\storeapp3\app\storeapp\shop>ruby add_to_cart.rb vitalik  car
file vitalik_cart.txt
```

**How to write?**

Comment: your second example is raising the error `Errno::ENOENT` which would occur prior to the division error. Thus it is being handled in rescue and using `puts` to show you the file name. It has nothing to do with where the `10/0` is but rather the fact that you are handling the error that is occurring first and thus it never gets to `10/0`. Also I have no idea what `i.to_real_item` is unless you have patched `String` to create this method because `i` is simply a `String` in this case.

Comment: @engineersmnky is'nt that a pretty good answer?

Comment: @papirtiger I don't feel that this question needs an answer it is a simple misunderstanding. I prefer to answer questions that involve an actual code example of some kind but in this case it would simply be redundant to his current code since this issue is not with the code but with the OP's understanding of his method functionality. If you would like the expendable reputation points feel free to post my comment as the answer I am sure at some point it will be accepted.

Comment: I just thought i was better than 90% of the answers on SO :)